# Not able to get values from HashTable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am new to Powershell. I have written a query and I am getting two columns from the query. What I want is Key = Col1 and Value = Col2. I am able to print the whole Hashtable, but I am not able to get the value in the format Col1['Col2] = x. Below is my code:

```
$query1 = "select top 5 Col1, Col2 from TableName"
$databases1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query1 -ConnectionString "ConnectionString"    
$hash = @{$databases1.Col1 = $databases1.Col2}
return $hash
```

The variable $hash returns as below:

```
Name                Value                                                                                                                                                                                           
----                -----                                                                                                                                                                                           
{a, b, c,...{1, 2, 3, 4...}
```

But I want to access it as `$hash['a'] = 1`
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You might want to consider that by doing this you could get an exception due to key collision, meaning that, one of the values on `Col1` (Keys) could be repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must *enumerate* the rows returned by your query and create an entry in the target hashtable for each:

```
$hash = [ordered] @{} # initialize the (ordered) hashtable
$databases1 | ForEach-Object {
  $hash[$_.Col1] = $_.Col2
}
```

Comment: No worries; thanks for accepting, @Lily.